# Running chutzpah on server using chrome

Tags: javascript, chutzpah

I have Java Script project where I am using Chutzpah and intend to run in server. I have tried changed to chrome in local and it works fine except a few test cases. Do we need to define the browser path to run in server?

Comment: @Matthew Manela Can you please help/ share your thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to define the local path to the browser if you are using chrome. See [this page](https://github.com/mmanela/chutzpah/wiki/Browser-Engines). I would recommend using JSDom if it works since it has no external dependencies.

[image]